# Asp.net render control client id in custom attribute of input field

Tags: c#, asp.net, expression

I have following html in my aspx page

```
<asp:Textbox id="myTextField" runat="server" cssclass="mycssclass" data-control-id="<%= search.ClientID %>"></asp:textbox>

<asp:Button ID="search" runat="server" Text="Search" />
```

the problem is `"<%= search.ClientID %>"` render as it is in the aspx file. i need to render the client id of control.

Comment: How is `search` control declared?

Comment: So when the button is clicked, nothing happens?

Comment: my concern is not with button. its with the expression in the asp text box. why rendering engine can not render the clientid of the button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thy this :

And call

`this.DataBind();` in `page_Load`

(notice change in `<%#`)

```
<asp:Textbox id="myTextField" runat="server" cssclass="mycssclass" data-control-id="<%# search.ClientID %>"></asp:textbox>
```

Another (more convenient solution) is to use html elements which are not server side :

```
  <input type='text' id="myTextField" runat="server" class="mycssclass" data-control-id="<%= search.ClientID %>" />
```

and then get it via `Request.Form[...]` ( via name attribute)

Comment: Are you asking why is `<%=` is not working while `<%#` does ?

Comment: Runat server controls can not contain yellow code. the logic is  - if they are already in server , then do it in server. But putting `#` is a databind thing. the control is on the page , but later/future to get data  via bind operation just like repeater ( which it's rows uses `#`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what the client ID will be, then search and read about the setting "ClientIDMode" - setting it to Static, for example, will set the client-side ID in the DOM equal to the server side ID that you set.  Just make sure have only one instance of that Control on your page otherwise you have more than one control with that ID, and that won't fly.  If that control will be in a repeater, item template or any other "repeating" control, then add an index counter for the loop to dynamically alter then ID slightly.